# Inner join summing up all rows instead of 1

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, one which contains Revenue data and one which contains Account data - the account data contains multiple rows per account ... the Revenue value assigned against FactPlanNo 327865 is $65,000 which is what I want to show, however because there are 4 rows in the RefGPNRoleMapping table for this account, it is multiplying $65,000 by 4

How do I stop this from happening so it brings back the following result:

```
    AccountNumber     AccountName       Rev
    0123456           MyAccount         65000 (instead of 260,000)
```

I currently have this query:

```
   select
   b.AccountNumber,
   b.AccountName,
   sum(a.Revenue) as rev
   from mdfl.FactPlanNo a
   inner join xyz.RefGPNRoleMapping b on
   a.FactPlanNo = b.FactPlanNo
   where b.FactPlanNo = '327865'
   group by b.AccountNumber, b.AccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Revenue per "FactPlanNo" */
SELECT FactPlanNo
     , Sum(Revenue) As rev
FROM   mdfl.FactPlanNo
GROUP
    BY FactPlanNo

/* Make it a subquery and join to that! */
SELECT b.AccountNumber
     , b.AccountName
     , revenues.rev
FROM   (
        SELECT FactPlanNo
             , Sum(Revenue) As rev
        FROM   mdfl.FactPlanNo
        GROUP
            BY FactPlanNo
       ) As revenues
 LEFT
  JOIN xyz.RefGPNRoleMapping As b
    ON b.FactPlanNo = revenues.FactPlanNo
WHERE  b.FactPlanNo = '327865'
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend, I still fairly new to SQL and haven't really gotten my head around sub-queries ... I added MIN to the select AccountNumber so that it brings back just one entry .... thanks

Comment: @user2957104 Do you understand the code I have provided? Please ask any questions you might have.